# Can't mock Cache::rememberForever

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, mockery

Using the following code

```
Cache::shouldReceive('rememberForever')
```

gives

```
Mockery_1_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::rememberForever() does not exist on this mock object
```

The call works (something is cached) but I just cannot test it.

The others (`Cache::get` for example) seem ok.

How should this be mocked ?

Comment: The `Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager` object doesn't have a `rememberForever()` method, but does have a `get()` method. That sounds more like something in the auth system.

Comment: src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository has it

Comment: Ah, so it does. But your mock is for the CacheManager. It looks like calling `get()` on the CacheManager returns an instance of the Repository. Perhaps you need to mock the Repository and use `shouldReceive` on that instead?